# Python function not outputting result from user input

Tags: python

Basically, I have this random meal code that asks the user to input the number 1. Once the user inputs the number 1, I want the if function to work and output the function create_recipe to create a randomly generated cake recipe. However, when the user inputs the number 1, the code does not work. How can I fix this? Is it because of my indentation? Please can someone help me. All responses are much appreciated. Here is the link: https://repl.it/@HarryBradley/ResponsibleForsakenAbilities#main.py Here is the code:

```
    num = input("Enter the number 1 ")
if num == 1:
  main_ingredient = ['chocolate', 'banana', 'salted caramel', 'carrot', 'bran']
  baking = ['cake', 'brownie', 'cupcake', 'muffin']
  measure = ['tbsp', 'tsp', 'cup']
  ingredient = [ 'flour', 'baking powder', 'butter', 'milk', 'eggs', 'vanilla', 'sugar']

  def create_recipe(main_ingredient, baking, measure, ingredient):
    m_ingredient = random.choice(main_ingredient)
    baking_ = random.choice(baking)
    ingredients = [random.choice(ingredient)]
    print("***", m_ingredient.title(), baking_.title() , "Recipe ***")
    print("Ingredients:")
    print(random.randint(1,3), random.choice(measure), m_ingredient)
    for i in ingredient:
      print(random.randint(1,3), random.choice(measure), i)

  create_recipe(main_ingredient, baking, measure, ingredient)
```

Answer (score 1):

`input(...)` always retuns a string. You need to cast it to an integer:

```
num = int(input("Enter the number 1 "))
```

Or write:

```
if num == "1":
```

Better yet: use a try/except block:

```
try:
    num = int(input("Enter the number 1 "))
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing int with string as in python `input()` returns String
use `num=int(input())`